# Setting Range Variables for use in Chart Properties VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My code is below.  I am having a few problems with the code below.

1) My `Range` variables `rngstart`, `rngend`, and `rngend2`are not returning `Range` variables and I'm not sure why.  I don't receive an error when I run the code, but (according to the locals window) their values return nothing.  I am stumped.

2) With these `Range` variables I would like to define data sources for use in a chart.  I have used the structure below to add charts to a workbook using the `ChartObject` object and `Chart` object. With `.SeriesCollection` is it possible to add multiple data sources?  And in case a vba charts expert happens upon this I would also like to:
- label two y-axis for each one of the data sets

All in all I am stuck on defining the `Range` variables to be used to set the source data for the charts.  Thanks for your help!

```
Dim aa As Integer
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
Dim RngStart As Range
Dim RngEnd  As Range
Dim RngEnd2 As Range
Dim DataRange1 As Range
Dim DataRange2 As Range
Dim DataRange3 As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart
Dim zz As Integer
Dim NumObs2

NumObs2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Range("C5", 
Range("C5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For aa = 5 To NumObs2

StartDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 9).value
EndDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AllDistanceMeasures").Cells(aa, 10).value

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ActiveSheet")

    Set RngStart = Cells.Find(What:=StartDate, After:=ActiveCell, 
LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set RngEnd = Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, After:=ActiveCell, 
LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1)

    Set RngEnd2 = Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

End With


    DataRange1 = RngStart.Address
    DataRange2 = RngEnd.Address
    DataRange3 = RngEnd2.Address

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("LowDistCharts")
Set chrt = sh.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 300, 300)
Set ch = chrt.Chart
Set DataRange1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(DataSht).Range(DataRange)
'Set DataRange2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Range(
'Set DataRange3 = Union(DataRange1,DataRange2)

With chrt
    .Height = 300
    .Width = 300
    .Top = 1 + ((aa - 4) * 300)
    .Left = 1
End With

With ch
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = aa & " " & StartDate & " to " & EndDate
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 8
    .ChartType = xlLine
    '.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range(DataRange1, DataRange2)
    .SeriesCollection(aa - 4).Add (DataRange1)
    .SeriesCollection(aa - 4).Add (Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range(DataRange1, DataRange2))
    .SeriesCollection(aa - 4).AxisGroup = 2
    .HasLegend = False
End With

For zz = 0 To NumObs - 1

    Sheets("ActiveSheet").Range(DataRange3).Offset(zz, 0).Resize(, 2).Copy
    Sheets("LowDistCharts").Cells(5, aa * 2 + 5).Offset(zz, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next zz
```

Comment: Is your sheet actually named `"ActiveSheet"`? What is `DataSht`? Are your dates `String`s or `Date`s?

Comment: @BigBen I'm guessing the name of his workbook is probably `"ActiveWorkbook"` too, haha :) But yes, I think you've found the problem!

Comment: Aside from the error noted above, the `With` block content is not "connected" to the `With`-scoped worksheet.  The leading `.` is missing from `Cells()`

Comment: @BigBen poor choice of a worksheet name, but I'm keeping it for now. DataSht is a worksheet variable assigned earlier in the code.  The dates in the worksheet are numeric(they return a 1 value when =TYPE(datevalue)).   good eye, I have since rewritten the "set" lines to read (.Sheets("ActiveWorkbook").Cells).  The code runs through, it is just that the problems arise in assigning multiple data ranges as source data for the charts (Im still unsure as to how to accomplish this) and in the last loop (zz)